# Hamiltonian for 2-qubit system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-computer

What is the general form of a Hamiltonian for a 2 qubit system?

The Hamiltonian for D-Wave system is:
$H = K_1\sigma_x^1 + K_2\sigma_x^2 + H_1\sigma_z^1 + H_2\sigma_z^2 + J_{12}\sigma_z^1\sigma_z^2  $
https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.01141

Is this true for all **superconducting qubit** system? If not, then what's the Hamiltonian? For instance, What's the Hamiltonian of the qubit in the IBM quantum computer?

Answer (score 1):

The hamiltonian of a two qubit system can be any $4\times4$ hermitian matrix. In general, [we can write this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1796840/basis-for-the-space-of-44-hermitian-matrices-with-specific-anti-commutation-pro)
\begin{align}
H = \sum_{i,j=0}^3 h_{ij} \,\sigma^1_i\sigma^2_j
\end{align}
where the coefficients $h_{ij}$ are real, and the $\sigma_i$ are Pauli matrices, with $\sigma_0$ the identity.

What the hamiltonian of a given quantum computer is will presumably depend on what you are trying to compute.

Comment: I understand that a Hamiltonian must be Hermitian. What I mean is the structure of Hamiltonian. For example, the Hamiltonian on the D-wave machine has that specific structure, why? Because that structure doesn't ignore some entries on the Hamiltonian...